# Promise.all doesn't enter

Tags: javascript

I have a Promise.all() that once completed I wan't it to move to another function.
Problem is that the Promise.all() functions doens't enter.

I put on an alert inside the function and it's not trigger ever.

When I tryed to use a foreach intead of the Promise.all() it runs over all the documents but executes the method insertData()  before the promise is resolved.

1 - Get user ref

2 - Promise.all()

3 - When finished call the insert data.

The alert 3 shows that the size is 5. Correct

The alert doc2 never shows.

```
    let userRef2 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(participantID);
        const result2 = await firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").where("user", "==", userRef2).get();
        alert("3 "+result2.size);

        await Promise.all(result2.map(async doc2 => {
            alert(doc2);

            //3 - Get video ref to compate to Array
            const videoFef = doc2.data().video.id;
            alert("videoFef "+videoFef);
            const doc3 = await firebase.firestore().collection("videos").doc(videoFef).get();
            if (!doc3.exists) {
                alert("Não exisste doc videos");
                return;
            }

            var sequence = doc3.data().sequenceNumberID;
            for (var i = 0; i < newRec.length; i++) {
                alert("5 ");
                if (String(sequence) !== String(newRec[i])) return;
                var index = newRec.indexOf(newRec[i]);
                if (index > -1) newRec.splice(index, 1);
            }

        })).catch(function (error) {
            alert(error);
        })
        // end of Promise.all

        insertData(newRec);
```

Comment: I have no experiance with firebase, but `result2.size` this doesn't look like it's an Array, so are you sure that `result2.map()` exists? Plus `alert()` is an awful tool for debugging, check out the devtools in your browser; you'll like em.

Comment: Probably because it's not an array

Comment: did a quick peek into the docs, `firebase.firestore().collection("recommendedVideo").where("user", "==", userRef2).get()` seems to return a [firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) wich has no `map()` method. Your console should show you the error.